# handle radio button behavior in multiple loop

Tags: angular, radio-button

I am having trouble in controlling the behavior of multiple radio select in multiple for loop.

In below demo, when I check radio of 1st block it is selecting the same radio in 2nd block too. Please have a look. Actually I need to select different radio option in different blocks.

```
demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/YpQZyv55tKxTGwDEi5gS?p=preview
```

Comment: Change your input box name and model to unique based on your parent loop

Comment: Have you checked the above solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in template

```
<div *ngFor="let a of abc; let i = index" >
  <p>{{a}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let enum of enum_details; let e = index">
    <label for="enum{{i+1}}{{e + 1}}">
      <input id="enum{{i+1}}{{e+1}}" [value]='enum.name' type="radio" name="enums{{i+1}}{{e+1}}" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected[i]">
      {{enum.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and change in component

```
radioSelected:string[] = []
```

At now you got you value in radioSelected array (radioSelected[0] for first radio bloc and radioSelected[ 1]  for second block)

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHEZrqm5wSzukboYDPJp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zn5a9PI4ya6h4qJgqKhY?p=preview)

---

You have to change `name` of your `input` based on `parent index` and `child index.`

**Example** : `name="enums{{i+1}}{{e+1}}"`

Then you need to create a dynamic model based on `parent index`

**Example** : `radioSelected[i]`

And replace  `radioSelected:any;` by `radioSelected:string[] = [];` in your component.

So use following code in your template,

```
 <input id="enum{{i+1}}{{e+1}}" [value]='enum.name' type="radio" name="enums{{i+1}}{{e+1}}" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected[i]">
```

You will get your input selected value in `radioSelected[index]`

Where `index` will be `0..n`.

**Example**: If you have selected value of `hello` loop is `Kumar` then you will access `this.radioSelected[0]` in your component to get this value.

Hopes this will help you !!